# SQL query: display different group value in different column

Tags: sql, group-by

I am trying to group by ticker, date and display their value in different columns for different tickers.
But I don't know the exact ticker name which are in my table.
original table(tickers may have other symbols besides A, B, C):

```
  date | ticker      | value
    -------------------------
     1 | A           | 5
     1 | B           | 3
     1 | C           | 2
     2 | A           | 5
     2 | B           | 3
     2 | C           | 2
     3 | A           | 5
     3 | B           | 3
     3 | C           | 2
.......
```

Write the SQL query to get the result dataframe:

```
  date | A           | B    | C
    --------------------------------
     1 | 5           | 3    | 2
     2 | 5           | 3    | 2
     3 | 5           | 3    | 2
```

Comment: This is called a `pivot`.  Depends on your `rdbms`.  There are lots of examples on SO on how to do this...

Comment: @sgeddes, thanks, but if I don't know the list of my tickers and the table is very large. how to do that? sorry I am new to sql, I checked pivot, it seems you have to list all your tickers first

Answer (score 1):

As sgeddes states, this is accomplished with a pivot.  You can create a pivot dynamically when you don't know all the values.  I gave an example of doing just that here

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/98776/dynamic-select-and-place-result-in-variable-columns/98809#98809

```
create Table  Questions
(
id int identity,
question_id int,
question_name varchar(255)
)
go

with CTEquestion
as
(
    select 1 QID
    union all
    Select QID+1
    from CTEquestion
    where QID < 11
)
insert questions
select QID, 'Question'+cast(QID as varchar(50))
from CTEquestion


insert QuestionAnswers
values ('2015-04-23', 'a1', 1, 'Canswer1')
    ,  ('2015-04-23', 'a1', 2, 'Ianswer2')
    ,  ('2015-04-23', 'a1', 3, 'Canswer3')
    ,  ('2015-04-23', 'a1', 4, 'Canswer4')
    ,  ('2015-04-23', 'a1', 5, 'Ianswer5')
    ,  ('2015-04-23', 'a1', 6, 'Ianswer6')
    ,  ('2015-04-23', 'a1', 7, 'Canswer7')
    ,  ('2015-04-23', 'a1', 8, 'Canswer8')
    ,  ('2015-04-23', 'a1', 9, 'Canswer9')
    ,  ('2015-04-23', 'a1', 10,'Canswer10')

insert QuestionAnswers
values (CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()), 'b2', 1, 'Canswer1')
    ,  (CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()), 'b2', 2, 'Canswer2')
    ,  (CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()), 'b2', 3, 'Canswer3')
    ,  (CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()), 'b2', 4, 'Canswer4')
    ,  (CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()), 'b2', 5, 'Canswer5')
    ,  (CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()), 'b2', 6, 'Ianswer6')
    ,  (CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()), 'b2', 7, 'Canswer7')
    ,  (CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()), 'b2', 8, 'Canswer8')
    ,  (CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()), 'b2', 9, 'Canswer9')
    ,  (CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()), 'b2', 10, 'Ianswer10')

insert QuestionAnswers
values (CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()), 'c3', 1, 'Ianswer1')
    ,  (CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()), 'c3', 2, 'Ianswer2')
    ,  (CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()), 'c3', 3, 'Canswer3')
    ,  (CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()), 'c3', 4, 'Ianswer4')
    ,  (CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()), 'c3', 5, 'Canswer5')
    ,  (CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()), 'c3', 6, 'Ianswer6')
    ,  (CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()), 'c3', 7, 'Canswer7')
    ,  (CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()), 'c3', 8, 'Canswer8')
    ,  (CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()), 'c3', 9, 'Canswer9')
    ,  (CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()), 'c3', 10, 'Ianswer10')

insert QuestionAnswers
values (CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()), 'a1', 1, 'Canswer1')
    ,  (CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()), 'a1', 2, 'Ianswer2')
    ,  (CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()), 'a1', 3, 'Canswer3')
    ,  (CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()), 'a1', 4, 'Canswer4')
    ,  (CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()), 'a1', 5, 'Canswer5')
    ,  (CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()), 'a1', 6, 'Canswer6')
    ,  (CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()), 'a1', 7, 'Canswer7')
    ,  (CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()), 'a1', 8, 'Canswer8')
    ,  (CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()), 'a1', 9, 'Canswer9')
    ,  (CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()), 'a1', 10, 'Ianswer10')
-->End test data creation

--straight join
select qa.user_id, qa.question_set, q.question_id, qa.answer
from Questions q
    join QuestionAnswers qa on qa.question_id=q.question_id
order by qa.user_id


--dynamic pivot 
DECLARE 
    @questionList varchar(max)
, @maxQID int
, @qid int

select @questionList='',@maxQID = MAX(question_id), @qid= MIN(question_id)
FROM Questions

while @qid <= @maxQID
begin
    set @questionList=@questionList+'['+cast(@qid as varchar(10))+']'

    select @qid=min(question_id)
    from Questions
    where question_id > @qid

    if @qid<=@maxQID
        set @questionList=@questionList+', '
end

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SQL = N'
select user_id, '+@questionList+'
from
(select q.question_id, qa.question_set, qa.user_id, qa.answer
from Questions q
    join QuestionAnswers qa on qa.question_id=q.question_id) x
PIVOT
(
max(answer)
FOR question_id in ('+@questionList+')
) pvt
order by user_id'

exec sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: Please specify which dbms this is for. (Far from ANSI SQL, and no dbms tagged in question.)

Answer (score 0):

If you know the ticker values you can do a `GROUP BY`. Use `CASE` to do conditional `SUM`:

```
select date,
       SUM(case when ticker = 'A' then value end) as A,
       SUM(case when ticker = 'B' then value end) as B,
       SUM(case when ticker = 'C' then value end) as C,
       ...
from tablename
group by date
```

Core ANSI SQL-99.

If the different ticker values are unknown, and may change between executions, you need product specific functionality. (The general behavior is that a `SELECT` always return the same number of columns - independent of table data!)

Comment: He stated he won't always know the ticker values. In which case, your solution will not work. It's not a matter of knowing the number of columns , rather pre-determining the values of known columns and then flipping it on its side or pivoting.

Comment: @SteveMangiameli, I wrote my answer before OP added "don't know the exact ticker name" part. My answer *was* exactly what OP asked for - when I wrote it. And if you don't know the the values, the number of columns is unknown (to the dbms as well to the programmer.)